Issue with 3D Secure Authentication during Credit Card Payment on Magento 2.4.7-p1
Hello Magento Community,
I am facing a critical issue during the credit card payment process on Magento version 2.4.7-p1. After entering the 3D Secure code, the system continuously displays the message "You are about to be authenticated" without completing the authentication process.
This issue is preventing our customers from successfully completing credit card payments through Magento. We have reviewed and followed recommended procedures for implementing 3D Secure in our environment, but the problem persists.
I would appreciate any advice, solutions, or experiences the community can share regarding this specific 3D Secure issue on Magento 2.4.7-p1. Additionally, if there are any insights on how CSP settings might impact 3D Secure functionality, that would be helpful to know.
It is crucial for us to resolve this issue promptly to ensure a seamless shopping experience for our customers.
Thank you in advance for your support and collaboration.

Which module do you use for credit card payments? Can you give the module name.
